# Can I use Keychain Across iPhone Apps, from an SDK?

Tags: iphone, keychain, sfhfkeychainutils

I am writing an SDK which will ship as a static library. Can I access the keychain to store data so that I can retrieve it in another app which also has my library? Seems like Apple would frown upon this, since I did not sign the apps, but am merely a passenger in the app's code.

Was looking at using "SFHFKeychainUtils" to help implement this. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, the keychain can only be shared across apps with the same Bundle Seed ID (which would be controlled at the signing level, as you say). As such, the only apps that would be able to share keychain access would be apps from any single developer. Cross-developer sharing is a no-go.

Check out more iOS security info [here in Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/Security_Overview/Introduction/Introduction.html).